# Discrete time state-space

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

$G = \left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A & B \\
\hline
C & D \\
\end{array}
\right]
= C(zI-A)^{-1}B+D$

Suppose:
1. $A,B,C,D$ are all real matrix.
2. $z = e^{j\theta}$, i.e. $r=1$ for simplicity.
3. $G^*$ denotes transpose conjugate of $G$.

$G^* = B^T(\frac{1}{z}I-A^T)^{-1}C^T+D^T=B^Tz^2(zI-z^2A^T)^{-1}C^T+D^T$
$G^* = \left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
z^2A & zC^T \\
\hline
zB^T & D^T \\
\end{array}
\right]
$

It seems like that. But my advisor said that there should be no frequency term $z$ in the state space representation.

How do I represent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the fact that $z$ is an operator that shifts functions in time. So your system becomes

$$\begin{align*}
x[k+1] &= A^T x[k+2] + C^T u[k+1] \\
x[k+2] &= A^{-T} x[k+1] - A^{-T} C^T u[k+1] \\
\\
y[k] &= B^T x[k+1] + D^T u[k] \\
y[k+1] &= B^T x[k+2] + D^T u[k+1] \\
&= B^T A^{-T} x[k+1] + (D^T - B^T A^{-T} C^T) u[k+1]
\end{align*}$$

$$G^* = \left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
A^{-T} & - A^{-T} C^T \\
\hline
B^T A^{-T} & D^T - B^T A^{-T} C^T \\
\end{array}
\right]$$

Comment: This help me a lot. Very nice